# ZF2 I cant access my module modle table in another controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-controller

This is my first class

```
<?php 

namespace Config\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Config\Model\Config;
use Config\Form\ConfigForm;

class ConfigController extends AbstractActionController
{ 
protected $configTable;



public function indexAction()
{
    $this->getSMTPConfigTable();
    return new ViewModel(array(
            'config' => $this->getConfigTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));

}

public function addAction()
{
    $form = new ConfigForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $config = new Config();
        $form->setInputFilter($config->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $config->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->getConfigTable()->saveConfig($config);

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/config');
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}

public function editAction()
{
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/config', array(
                'action' => 'add'
        ));
    }

    try {
        $config = $this->getConfigTable()->getConfig($id);
    }
    catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/config', array(
                'action' => 'index'
        ));
    }

    $form  = new ConfigForm();
    $form->bind($config);
    $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setInputFilter($config->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->getConfigTable()->saveConfig($form->getData());

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/config');
        }
    }

    return array(
            'id' => $id,
            'form' => $form,
    );
}

public function getConfigTable()
{
    if (!$this->configTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->configTable = $sm->get('Config\Model\ConfigTable');
    }
    return $this->configTable;
}

public function getSMTPConfigTable()
{
    $pr=$this->getConfigTable()->fetchAll();
    return $pr;
}

    }
```

in another module class how am I do it? I have trying most ways but I am failing please help me.(sorry for my English )
I need $temp=new ConfigController();
$temp->getSMTPConfigTable();

Comment: Show us what you have tried. What do you mean by "another module class" ?

Answer (score 4):

I first want to check if I understand your question correct. Reading the name and the content of the question I assume you ask about a way to get the ConfigTable (Model) in another controller or class of the module(s).

To understand how the object and services are managed in ZF2 I advice you to have a look at this ZF2 manual page:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html

If you pay attention to the section "Creating a ServiceLocator-aware class" of the page, you will find out that you can get access to any object registered with the service manager via the service manager itself. The service manager in its terms is injected in every object that implements the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` or simply has method named `setServiceLocator()`.

Having that clear, the ZF2's `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` implements this interface meaning you can get the service manager in the object and therefore any other object registered with it. If you have a look at the following method (from your `Config\Controller`) there is a good example of getting the model from  the service manager:

```
public function getConfigTable()
{
    if (!$this->configTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->configTable = $sm->get('Config\Model\ConfigTable'); // <-- HERE!
    }
    return $this->configTable;
}
```

So, in every class that is created via the `ServiceManager` and has the `setServiceLocator()` (and optionaly `getServiceLocator()`) methods you can access your model in the same way:

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
// or 
$sm = $this->serviceLocator; // or whatever attribute you have set it to.
$configTable = $sm->get('Config\Model\ConfigTable');
```

About how to call the `fetchAll()` method of your model I leave this decision to you where to do it.

Comment: Little more in-depth than what i did provide. Well explained!

Comment: Thanks @Sam, indeed your answer also covers his question well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I can use this method only same module.
I have trying other module called HTMLEmail It cant 
<?php
namespace HTMLEmail\Controller;
use Config\Controller\ConfigController;
//----------------------
function sendMail($htmlBody, $subject, $from, $to)
 {
$arr=$this->getConfigTable()->fetchAll();
//-------------------------
}public function getConfigTable()
{if (!$this->configTable) {
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$this->configTable = $sm->get('Config\Model\ConfigTable');
}return $this->configTable;
}
problem is Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Comment: In the other Controllers you don't need to use `Config\Controller\ConfigController`. You just call `$arr = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config\Model\ConfigTable')->fetchAll(); `

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the part, where you use the `ServiceManager`

You would register your `TableGateway` (or whatever it is you're using as "Model Table") to the `ServiceManager` like this:

```
//Module.php 
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'my-model-gateway' => function($sm) {
               $gw = new MyTableGateway($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
               return $gw;
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This is only a showcase-scenario - it won't work copy-paste like this for you - i'm not getting clever out of your code, but you can use this simple example to know what is done. I register a service called `my-model-gateway` and this service creates a class called `MyTableGateway`. This class will be injected the default `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` via Constructor-Injection.

Using this, you would access this Service from ANY Controller of ANY Module like this:

```
$gw = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('my-model-gateway');
```

Hope this can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a contructor for that. Try with this:

```
class ConfigController {
   function __construct() {
   }
}
```

Even if it's empty, you will get the instance of the class and then you will be able to access to all parameters. Maybe you will need to create an init too for the general setting of the class.